# How to enable and disable a button with toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I have an edit button in html that is disabled.

```
<a href="#" disabled class="btn btn-default" id="editButton">Edit</a>
<table>
...
<tr class="clickable-row>...</tr>
...
</table>
```

and in js i have make a toggle to select a row in table

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function (event) {
        $(".clickable-row").not(this).removeClass('selected');


$(this).toggleClass('selected');
});

$(".clickable-row").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected'))
        $("#editButton").removeAttr("disabled");
    else
        $("#editButton").attr("disabled");
});
```

});
i can select a row it works, and i want to enable the edit button if there is a selected row. and disable when it's not. but the code does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Bootstrap buttons using `button` elements are disable using the property `disabled`.
- Bootstrap buttons using `a` elements are disabled using the class  `disabled`.

**If you change your `a` element to `button` element, use this approach:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".clickable-row").click(function(event) {
    //$(".clickable-row").not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    $("#editButton").prop("disabled", !$(this).hasClass('selected'));
  });
});
```

```css
.clickable-row td {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button disabled class="btn btn-default" id="editButton">Edit</button>
</p>
<table>
  <tr class="clickable-row">
    <td>Click me!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**If you need to use `a` elements, remove the property `disabled` and add the class `disabled` to the button.**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".clickable-row").click(function(event) {
    //$(".clickable-row").not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      $("#editButton").removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
      $("#editButton").addClass('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.clickable-row td {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="disabled btn btn-default" id="editButton">Edit</a>
</p>
<table>
  <tr class="clickable-row">
    <td>Click me!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `prop`, not `attr`.

```
$("#editButton").prop("disabled", true);
$("#editButton").prop("disabled", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try combining your logic rather than having two click handlers.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".clickable-row").click(function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $editButton = $("#editButton");

    $(".clickable-row").not(this).removeClass('selected');

    if ($this.hasClass("selected")) {
      $this.removeClass("selected");
      $editButton.prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
      $this.addClass("selected");
      $editButton.prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `a` tag doesn't support the `disabled` attribute. You can change it to a `button` for that purpose.

Also, you should remove the `selected` class from the other rows as it would be troublesome to have multiple selected rows when the "edit" event fires.

```js
$( ".clickable-row" ).click(function()
{
  $( this ).toggleClass( "selected" ).siblings().removeClass('selected');
  
  if ($(this).hasClass('selected'))
  {
    $("#editButton").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
  
  else
  {
    $("#editButton").attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
});
```

```css
.selected
{
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="editButton" disabled>Edit</button>
      
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="clickable-row">
      <td>Cell #1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clickable-row">
      <td>Cell #2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to stick to the `a` tag, using [Kosh Very's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48832977/4770813) you could seriously refactor your `click` event like this:

```
$(".clickable-row").click(function (event) {
    //deselect other rows
    $(".clickable-row").not(this).removeClass('selected');
    //select this row
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    //set the button's "disabled" property based on the state of selected row; 
    //"disabled true" if row is selected, "disabled false" otherwise
    $("#editButton").prop("disabled", !$(this).hasClass('selected'));
    //and you can query the state of the button like this:
    console.log('Edit button '+ ($('#editButton').prop('disabled') ? 'disabled':'enabled'));
});
```